# What are the exact applications of Functor, PointedFunctor, ApplicativeFunctor and Monad?

Tags: scala, haskell, types, monads, functor

I have been studying Scala (and Haskell by extension) for some time now and I'm totally captured by their type system and functional paradigm. Quite recently I stumbled upon "Type Level Programming" and got dragged into things like Functors and other things I haven't heard about (except for Monad, which I knew was something of a mystic nature but had no idea of what to make use of it!).
I studied the concepts in Haskell (and got bewitched by its type system and type inference capabilities by the way) and I kinda have a firm grasp of what it means for a type to be Functor, PointedFunctor, ApplicativeFunctor or Monoid in a purely technical level (I still don't know what a Monad is even in technical level) but I'm feeling like an idiot since I see no uses for all this except that perhaps a good categorization of some concepts is acquired (?). What are these things useful for ? Why make life so complex? Why study these stuff and categorize them into various classes?

Comment: Nitpicking: I wouldn't say these simple type classes qualify as type level programming (and I've never seen them categorized at such), though they obviously use types. Type-level programming does a lot more with types.

Comment: @delnan Tnx for the clarification. Quite right. As mentioned in the question, I was dragged to them while studying type level programming. Not that they are themselves type level programming.

Comment: Voted for reopen: The question might be quite general, but I think it is a common one, and we got here already some good, "constructive" answers. Not all "open" questions are bad or prone to flame wars, they can often lead to interesting insights by casting light on a topic from different angles.

Comment: @Landei I gave up on that long time ago ;-)

Answer (score 9):

> Why make life so complex?

They are all there to make life more *simple*!

Firstly, they make the code we write cleaner and clearer.

Secondly, they increase our expressiveness without adding genuinely new language features.
For example, Monads let you use a standard syntax to express complex computational contexts, Functors let you think and program in standard ways about data structures, and Applicative Functors let you treat effectful or complex computational contexts as simply as you treat straightforward data, letting you use the functional paradigm cleanly outside pure data.

They all help code reuse and help us understand each others' code because they give us a standard way of thinking about things.

Once you're used to them, you'll not want to do without them!

Answer (score 5):

They are all abstractions. Eg. a monoid is something that supports a zero element and addition (must be associative). Examples would be integers, lists, strings etc. I think its rather nice to have a single common "interface" for all those different types.

So why are they useful? You can write a generic sum function for all monoids for example. Instead of writing one for string, integers and so on you only write one generic function. I think that's quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

We should first ask: **What are functors, monads, ...**. Unless we know what these concept are (mean) it's difficult to talk about their uses.

These concept come from [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). 
They arise from the fact that many many objects in mathematics (and consequently in functional programming) share some common, abstract properties. Once we know and understand these properties, we can use them to write very generic code that is reusable for very large amount of tasks.

---

To give an example: Everybody knows function

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

Having a function from `a` to `b` we can create a function that works on lists `[a]`. [Functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) are generalization of this concept. Anything that can be mapped over in this way (and preserves [functor laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor)) is called a functor. So `Functor` declars

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

In the case of lists `f` becomes `[]`. With `fmap` we can map over lists (there it's equal to `map`) but also over `Maybe`s, various collections, trees, even over functions.

See also

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/good-book-lecture-notes-about-category-theory
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21128/when-to-learn-category-theory

Answer (score 3):

Additionally I want to point out that monads are not "mystic". Especially container-like monads (list, Maybe, Identity) are quite easy to understand. They are similiar to functors, but with a twist: Using `fmap` the "shape" (e.g. number of elements in a list) of the original functor is preserved, e.g. you can't use `fmap` to implement something like `filter`. That's why monads have a function called "bind" (in Haskell it's `(>>=)`) which allows this kind of thing, but they aren't magic either (e.g. for lists, it's the same as good old `concatMap`). Additionally monads have a function `return` to wrap a single value.

Now a lot of other, not "container-like" things are monads. There are monads that can operate on "stored computations" (`Cont` for continuation monad). They can provide (`Reader`), collect (`Writer`) or hold (`State`) some kind of "additional context". A very useful "context" is the "state of the rest of the world", better known as `IO`. In that case the type system (especially the restrictions imposed by polymorphism and type classes) can shield against unwanted interactions, and force a certain computation order (which is not trivial in a lazy language), so we need no dirty hacks or language back-doors in order to do IO in a pure language. Some people think this is kind of magic, but it's just clever use of the type system, and monads are not the only solution for this problem (e.g. the language Clean uses "uniqueness types" for this).

Answer (score 1):

"What are these thigs useful for?"
Ah! you could use them to write FizzBuzz:
http://dave.fayr.am/posts/2012-10-4-finding-fizzbuzz.html